# display JSON with jQuery: append as child

Tags: jquery, json, list, append

I have the following code to visualize a json:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
    $.each(data.resolved_names, function(index,resolved){
        var wrap = $('<p />', {'class': 'names', 'id' :'id_'+index}),
        a = $('<a />', {'href': 'http://domain.com', 'text': resolved.supplied_name_string}), 
        liste = $('<ul />', {'class':'liste'});

        //output html with this
        $('#names').append(wrap.append(a).append(liste));
   });
});
```

the output is:

```
<p id="id_0">
    <a href="http://doamin.com">supplied name 0</a>
     <ul class="liste"></ul>
</p>
     <p id="id_1">
   ....
 </p>
 ...
```

inside this "parent" each.function i got:

```
$.each(resolved.results, function(i,result) { 
    ...
    $.each(splitpath, function(i,v) {
      //result of this "inner" function should become child of ul-element
    });
});
```

Now i want to append the result of the additonal functions as a child of the ul-element "liste"

so the output would look like:

```
 <p id="id_0">
    <a href="http://doamin.com">supplied name 0</a>
     <ul class="liste">
        <li>stuff from the "inner" function</li>
     </ul>
 </p>
 <p id="id_1">
   ....
 </p>
 ...
```

How to do that?

Comment: Call `liste.append('<li>'+v+'</li');` within the each function as that iterator should already be unique to it's parent if it's using  data from it's parent object.

Comment: You may want to check out http://handlebarsjs.com/ for displaying json.

Comment: thank you liste.append was the solution - and i gonna check handlebarsjs for less frustrating templating